# Public Folders Appear empty to a particular user, when we know they are not

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, public-folders, windows-sbs-2011

Public Folders Appear empty to a particular user, when we know they are not - It's pretty simple really, this user should see the contents of this folder, but they can't!

Any ideas why you'd see messages flash on the screen for a split second, and then never appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can the user view the contents in OWA? If so, then it's an Outlook view problem and you should reset their view. If not, then I'd take a look at the permissions on the PF, what roles have which permissions, is the user listed in the permissions or is the user a member of a group that has permissions and what roles/permissions are granted to the user or group. PF folder access is based on roles (Author, Editor, Contributor, etc) and each role has a specific set of permissions on the PF. You can also set custom role permissions.

Comment: I didn't consider the view in OWA - I will be looking into this in a few moments, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Public Folder permissions are not recursive.  Are the users able to see contents of some but not all folders?

I second the other Answer that asks about OWA experience.  It is troubling that content seems to "flash" then disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with Outlook 2010 where a calendar in a public folder was almost blank - only appointments from a month ago were showing, but nothing recent, and nothing I added would show up.

Turns out I was accessing the public folder calendar through a favourite, and going the long way and accessing the public folder directly allowed me to see everything.

So check how you are accessing the folder, and if you're using a favourite, try going direct and see if it makes a difference.